# Giving error The HTTP status code "600" is not valid. after submitting ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

On form submit I got this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 462:The HTTP status code "600" is not valid.

```
$("#personal_info_form").submit(function(event) {
    var name = $("#Name").val();
    var email = $("#Email").val();
    var mobile = $("#Mobile").val();

    if (name != "" && email != "" && mobile != "") 
    {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
        //get form GET/POST method
        $('#main_container').addClass('hidden');
        $('#sub_container').removeClass('hidden');
        var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object

        $.ajax({
            url: 'new_register_flow',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            async:true,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(response) { //

            console.log(response);
            var url = response;

            openinatamojo(url);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This has rather little to do with the client-side form that sends the data. The line mentioned in the error message in that PHP file is the culprit.

Comment: are you sure your `url` is correct?

Comment: so  please show `Response.php` which is where the invalid http status originates

Answer (score 2):

I think ajax url is wrong. Please add '/' in url.

Use below line in ajax call.

```
url: '/new_register_flow',
```